# Only admin can login if user is not logged in user show error message and log out (middleware) Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I create a custom middleware if user admin user than and only then user login. Else show error message and logout and redirect to login. But when ever I clicked on logout link unable to logout that user. How to fix it?

```
 class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
    { /** * The path to the "home" route for your application. * * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login. * * @var string */ 
public const HOME = 'admin/dashboard';
    
        public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
            {
                if (Auth::check()) {
                    $loginUser = Auth::user();
                    if ($loginUser && $loginUser->user_type != 'Admin') {
                      //  return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
                    
                        return redirect('/home')->with('error', 'Invalid credentials');
                        //return redirect->back()->with('message', 'Invalid credentials');
                    }
                    return $next($request);
                 } else {
                    return redirect('/login');
                 }
        
            }
        }
        
        
    On the view page:
        
                            <form action="{{ route('admin.admin-logout') }}" method="post">
               @csrf
               <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="mr-2 fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</button>
              </form>
         <div class="card">
                        
        
                        <div class="card-body">
                            @if (session('error'))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                              {{ session('error') }}
                            </div>
                            @endif
                            @if (session('status'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                    {{ session('status') }}
                                </div>
                            @endif
        
                            
        
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us your route config file?

Comment: class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * This is used by Laravel authentication to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = 'admin/dashboard';

Comment: Can you edit your original post and place it there?